# JSON from ruby to mongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm new in ruby and mongo. I developed a Ruby script, which generates JSON from YAML files. How can I send this JSON to MongoDB?

I started from:

```rb
require "mongo"
client = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:27017'])
database = Mongo::Database.new(client,'test')
collection = Mongo::Collection.new(database,test)
collection.create()
```

and when I want to insert my JSON files in a collection, I do this:

```rb
collection.insert(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(my_json_files)
```

but that doesn't work, becuse when I look in mongoDB, the collection result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To insert JSON data into a MongoDB database using Ruby, you need to use the MongoDB Ruby driver, which you have already required in your script. However, your code is slightly incorrect. Here are the steps you need to follow:

First, ensure that you have installed the MongoDB Ruby driver. If you haven't, you can install it using the following command:

```
require 'mongo'
client = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:27017'], :database => 'test')
```

Next, you need to convert your JSON data into a Ruby hash object before inserting it into the MongoDB collection. The `JSON.parse` method can be used for this:

```
require 'json'
my_hash = JSON.parse(my_json_files)
```

Now, you are ready to insert your data into the MongoDB collection. You can use the insert_one or insert_many methods of the collection to insert one or many documents respectively:

```
client[:test].insert_one(my_hash)
```

This will insert the hash object into the 'test' collection in the 'test' database. If the collection does not exist, it will be created automatically.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for answer. I just try to run the script with this suggestion, but ruby console say me "JSON::ParseError: unecpected token at ...(rest of json that try to parse)"

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is valid? You can use an online JSON validation tool to check that (just make sure it does not include any sensitive data)

Comment: i check json files and i adjust the format, but now occurred another problem when i run the script.  That is: #<NoMethidError: undefined method  'map' for ---(the rest of json file) :String>

Comment: Do you see where the 'map' method is used that could cause the issue?

Comment: yes, i saw, but i dont understand why occured another problem:  i wrote your exact code and when i try to run ruby script,the script doesnt write on the collection. sorry but  i dont know why